# Batch convert PNGs to individual PDFs while maintaining deep folder hierarchy in bash

Tags: image, bash, pdf, batch-processing, imagemagick-convert

I've found a solution that claims to do one folder, but I have a deep folder hierarchy of sheet music that I'd like to batch convert from png to pdf. What do my solutions look like?

I will run into a further problem down the line, which may complicate things. Maybe I should write a script? (I'm a total n00b fyi)

The "further problem" is that some of my sheet music spans more than one page, so if the script can parse filenames that include "1of2" and "2of2" to be turned into a single pdf, that'd be neat.

What are my options here?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe start with [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

As an alternative, the following should be faster (as it does the conversions in parallel) and also able to handle larger numbers of files:

```
find . -name \*.png -print0 | parallel -0 convert {} {.}.pdf
```

It uses **GNU Parallel** which is readily available on Linux/Unix and which can be simply installed on OSX with `homebrew` using:

```
brew install parallel
```

**Original Answer (as accepted)**

If you have `bash` version 4 or better, you can use `extended globbing` to recurse directories and do your job very simply:

First enable `extended globbing` with:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Then recursively convert PNGs to PDFs:

```
mogrify -format pdf **/*.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over `png` files in a folder hierarchy, and process each one as follows:

```
find /path/to/your/files -name '*.png' |
while read -r f; do
    g=$(basename "$f" .png).pdf
    your_conversion_program <"$f" >"$g"
done
```

To merge `pdf`-s, you could use `pdftk`. You need to find all `pdf` files that have a `1of2` and `2of2` in their name, and run `pdftk` on those:

```
find /path/to/your/files -name '*1of2*.pdf' |
while read -r f1; do
    f2=${f1/1of2/2of2}                            # name of second file
    ([ -f "$f1" ] && [ -f "$f2" ]) || continue    # check both exist
    g=${f1/1of2//}                                # name of output file
    (! [ -f "$g" ]) || continue                   # if output exists, skip
    pdftk "$f1" "$f2" output "$g"
done
```

See:

- [bash string substitution](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/string-manipulation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding a deep folder hierarchy you may use find with -exec option.
First you find all the PNGs in every subfolder and convert them to PDF:

```
find ./ -name \*\.png -exec convert {} {}.pdf \;
```

You'll get new PDF files with extension ".png.pdf" (image.png would be converted to image.png.pdf for example)
To correct extensions you may run find command again but this time with "rename" after -exec option.

```
find ./ -name \*\.png\.pdf -exec rename s/\.png\.pdf/\.pdf/ {} \;
```

If you want to delete source PNG files, you may use this command, which deletes all files with ".png" extension recursively in every subfolder:

```
find ./ -name \*\.png -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: so is this syntax applicable in bash, or is this something I would put into a script? Do I execute this inside the folder I want the files converted in? Also, I could just change "convert" to "mogrify" to have it replace the files, right?

Comment: It's applicable in both - bash and inside script.

Comment: You should execute it in a folder which contains all the subfolders where you have put your PNGs. The command searches recursively down the folder structure (you can restrict it to search only some levels of folder structure with -maxdepth and -mindepth options).
Yes, find -exec will work with mogrify too. In fact, it should work with any command.
Little explanation:
during execution of command `{}` is replaced by bash with names of files found with first part of command (`find ./ -name \*\.png`)
and `\;` must always be at the end of command

Comment: Please note that while backslash-escaping the `.` in  `\*\.png` doesn't hurt, it can also mistakenly suggest that `.` is a special char. to the shell, which it is not (unlike `*`, which indeed does need escaping, because it is a globbing char.); perhaps a simpler approach is to single-quote the entire argument: `'*.png'`

Answer (score 0):

if i understand :

- you want to **concatenate all your png files from a deep folders structure into only one single pdf**.

so...

1. insure you png are ordered as you want in your folders
2. be aware you can redirect output of a command (say a search one ;) ) to the input of convert, and tell convert to output in one pdf.

General syntax of convert :

```
convert 1.png 2.png ... global_png.pdf
```

The following command :

```
convert `find . -name '*'.png -print` global_png.pdf
```

- searches for png files in folders from cur_dir
- redirects the output of the command `find` **to the input of** `convert`, this is done by ***back quoting*** `find` command
- converts works and output to pdf file

(this very simple command line works fine **only with unspaced filenames**, don't miss quoting the wild char, and back quoting the `find` command ;) )

[edit]Care....

be sure of what you are doing.

if you delete your png files, you will just loose your original sources...

- it might be a very bad practice...
- using `convert` without any tricky `-quality` output option could create an enormous pdf file... and you might have to re-`convert` with `-quality "60"` for instance...
- so keep your original sources until you do not need them any more

Comment: I don't think the intent is to create a _single_ PDF for _all_ input files. Passing a command's output via an unquoted command substitution (`\`...\`` ) as arguments is not robust, and breaks with filenames with embedded spaces, for instance.

Comment: yesssssss.... you're absolutly right... "spaces"... i never use them... bizarrement... ;DD