# find seems to be much slower with -print0 option

Tags: bash, find, imagemagick

I am trying to resize photos larger than specific dimensions for 100s of thousands of photos collected by a system over past 10 years. I am using `find` and `imagemagick`

I wrote this script to do it.

```
#!/bin/bash
ResizeSize="1080^>"
Processing=0

find . -type f -iname '*JPG' -print0 | \

while IFS= read -r -d '' image; do
    ((Processing++))
    echo Processing file: $Processing
    echo Resizing """$image""" 
    convert """$image""" -resize $ResizeSize """$image""___" 
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
      rm """$image"""
      if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
        mv """$image""___" """$image"""    
    else
      echo something wrong with resize
      exit 1
    fi
done
```

The script works on a small amount of files but it takes a long time to start with lots of files. I have tested on the command line `find . -type f -iname '*JPG' -print0` vs `find . -type f -iname '*JPG'`. The later finds files within a few seconds but the former takes minutes before anything is found? Unfortunately the `-print0` is required for dealing with filenames with special characters (which are mainly spaces in my case). How can I get this script to be more efficient?

Comment: Are you sure you're just not experiencing file system caching benefits in you second call? Try calling your slower `find .. -print0` twice in a row.

Comment: Triple quotes aren't a thing in shell. `"""$image"""` is just a quoted string concatenated with two empty strings on either side.

Comment: @randomir I have tested that this is not a caching thing. The result is the same every time. I should mention that I am using BSD (OSX) find.

Comment: @chepner I was struggling to get this script to work. Somewhere I read I should be using double quotes, when that didn't work I gave triple quotes a go and now it works. I don't understand why really, but I am guessing its because my files have spaces. I did try escaping the outside quotes but that didnt work either. Well at least for the line `convert """$image""" -resize $ResizeSize """$image""___"`

Comment: The only issue that might pop up is related to your attempt at creating a temporary file. `"$image__"` attempts to expand a parameter named `image__`, not append `__` to the value of the parameter `image`. That, however, can be accommodated by using the "long" form of parameter expansion: `"${image}__"`.

Comment: @cmdln, your "triple quotes" (`"""$var"""`) are effectively equal to proper double quotes (`"$var"`). You are simply concatenating empty strings `""` before and after the `"$var"` string.

Comment: As an aside, what version of `bash` are you using?  A simple `for f in **/*.JPG; do` will be a lot simpler than dealing with `find`.

Comment: I regularly resize 60,000+ images per day - you need to use **GNU Parallel** - please see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42670939/2836621 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38838907/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not reproduce the behavior you're experiencing, but can think of two possible explanations.

**First**, you might be experiencing positive effects of page (disk) caching.

When you call `find` for the first time, it traverses files (metadata in inodes), actually reading from the data media (HDD) via kernel `syscall`. But kernel (transparently to `find`, or other applications) also stores that data in unused areas of memory, which acts as a cache. If this data is read again later, it can be quickly read from this cache in memory. This is called [page caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache).

So, your second call to `find` (no matter what output separator is used) will be *a lot faster*, assuming you are searching over the same files, with the same criteria.

**Second**, since `find`'s output might be buffered, if your files are in many different locations, it might take some time before the actual first output to the `while` command. Also if the output is line-buffered, that would explain why `-print0` variant takes longer to produce the first output (since there are no lines at all).

You can try running `find` with unbuffered output, via `stdbuf` command:

```
stdbuf -o0 find . -iname '*.jpg' -type f -print0 ...
```

One more thing, unrelated to this; to speed-up your `find` search, you might want to consider calling it like this:

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -type f -print0
```

Here we put the `-iname` test before the `-type` test in order to avoid having to call `stat(2)` on every file. Even better would be to remove the `-type` test all together, if possible.

Comment: `stdbuf` sorts out the issue. I had to install coreutils for OSX to get it and add it to the path like this `export PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH`

Comment: Ok, so it was the buffering. I'm glad you made it work.